# SRC de imagen no se actualiza en javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Tengo una aplicación que permite mostrar una lista de imágenes, donde cada imagen se la puede girar, una vez que el usuario gira las imágenes o las ordena las envió a través de socket.io para mostrarlas en un slide. El proceso de girar la imagen esta bien ya que en mi servidor si se cambia, pero en mi slider cuando envío por el socket la imagen no gira sino que se muestra como en su estado anterior, este es mi codigo

```
function SetearArchivo(item) {
    $scope.tipo_archivo = array[item].tipo_archivo;
    if($scope.tipo_archivo == 1){
        video.pause();
        if(angularPlayer.getMuteStatus()){
            $timeout( function(){
            angularPlayer.mute();
            }, 0);
        }
        cambiar(array[item].url);
    }else{
        if(!angularPlayer.getMuteStatus()){
            $timeout( function(){
            angularPlayer.mute();
            }, 0);
        }
        document.querySelectorAll('.slide2')[0].src = array[item].url;
        video.play();
    }
}

function cambiar(url){
    document.querySelectorAll('.slide')[0].removeAttr("src");
    document.querySelectorAll('.slide')[0].attr("src", url);
}
```

Pienso que es cache porque cuando actualizo la vista y envío por el socket la imagen cambia, pero lo que necesito es que se actualice automaticamente

Comment: Tienes una errata en la última línea: hay dos puntos antes de la llamada a `attr`. Además no necesitas borrar el atributo antes

Comment: perdona ya edite mi pregunta